# How to get date from sql server in user specified format

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want get date from sql server in user specified format using GETDATE() function.

if i give this query

```
select GETDATE()
```

then it is displating output date in this format

```
2015-03-17 07:29:58.377
```

but i want output like this .

```
2015-03-17
```

what statement should be added with query to get the result.
help me from this problem.

Comment: Use `CONVERT`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `convert()`:

```
select convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 121)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just have a look to the following link. which provides more conversion options.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2012 onward you may use FORMAT() which is a bit more intuitive than recalling style numbers.

e.g. 
select FORMAT( GETDATE() , 'yyyy-MM-dd' )

see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/hh213505.aspx

however do note the second parameter is case sensitive

- 'yyyy-MM-dd' works
- 'YYYY-MM-DD' would only work for the MM

Comment: Thanks for your help but i am using sql server 2008

Comment: I know, my contribution is for other readers who might read this page, plus one day you will be on a later version and you might remember this. :)